# Since the limit of the sequence $b^n$ where $0<b<1$ converges to zero does it follow $\lim \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$ converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The question is in the title. For a fixed number $b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $0<b<1$,  I can prove that the sequence $b^n$ converges to zero.

*Proof*

Choose $K(\epsilon) = \lfloor \frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln b} \rfloor + 1$. Then for all $n \geq K$ we have $$ \ln b^n < \ln \epsilon \implies \left|b^n - 0 \right| < \epsilon $$

So, can I say something like... clearly we have ,  $ 0 < n/(n+1) < 1, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ so set $b = n/(n+1)$ then 
$$ \lim \left(\frac{n}{n+1} \right)^n = 0$$

Comment: The problem is that when you set $\;b=\frac n{n+1}\;$ this is **not** a constant number....and this makes **all** the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your term in the form
$$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion is:  "If $0 < b_n < 1, \forall n \ge 1$, and $b_n \to 0$. Does it follow that $b_n^n \to 0$? ".  It is *true* because $0 < b_n^n < b_n$. So by squeeze lemma, its limit is $0$. The $b_n = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$ in your question does not converge to $0$, and it converges to $1$ instead. So the proposed lemma you had is not applicable. And the limit of it is $\dfrac{1}{e}$ which is positive.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0\lt\left(\frac12\right)^{1/n}\lt1$ the logic in your argument could be used to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac12\right)^{1/n}\right)^n=0
$$
However, for each $n$, $\left(\left(\frac12\right)^{1/n}\right)^n=\frac12$. The theorem you state assumes a fixed $b$; it does not necessarily hold for a varying $b$.

Comment: This example is simpler than the sequence in question. +1